# lognormal distribution Method in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have to find lognormal distribution in C#,

In Excel we have a Function

LOGNORM.DIST(x,mean,standard_dev,cumulative)

Is there any similar method in c# through which I can find lognormal distribution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Math.NET as mathematical library which includes lognormal distribution. See here: http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Distributions/LogNormal.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try out the folowing code:

```cs
namespace System
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a pseudo-random number generator that implements a lognormal distribution.
    /// </summary>
    internal class LogNormalRandom : Random
    {
        // stored previous value
        private double _prevSample = double.NaN;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a random floating point number between 0.0 and 1.0.
        /// Lognormal distribution is used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A double precision floating point number that is greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.
        /// </returns>
        protected override double Sample()
        {
            // If there is a previous value, return it.
            if (!double.IsNaN(_prevSample))
            {
                doubleresult = _prevSample;
                _prevSample = double.NaN;
                return result;
            }

            // Otherwise, calculate the following values.
            // polar method of McLaren-Marsaglia.
            double u, v, s;
            do
            {
                u = 2 * base.Sample() - 1;
                v = 2 * base.Sample() - 1; // [-eleven)
                s = u * u + v * v;
            }
            while (u <= -1 || v <= -1 || s >= 1 || s == 0);
            double r = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(s) / s);

            _prevSample = r*v;
            return Math.Exp(r * u);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance <see cref="T:System.LogNormalRandom" />
        /// with initial default value depending on time.
        /// </summary>
        public LogNormalRandom() : base()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance <see cref="T:System.LogNormalRandom" />
        /// using the specified initial value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="seed">The number used to calculate the seed value
        /// sequences of pseudo-random numbers. If specified
        /// negative number, its absolute value is used.</param>
        public LogNormalRandom(int seed) : base(seed)
        {
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a random double precision floating point number,
        /// with the specified mathematical expectation and standard deviation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="expectation">Mathematical expectation.</param>
        /// <param name="deviation">Standard deviation.</param>
        /// <returns>Random double precision floating point number.</returns>
        public double NextDouble(double expectation = 0, double deviation = 1)
        {
            return Sample() * deviation + expectation;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a random double precision floating point number,
        /// within the specified limits with a probability of 99.73%
        /// (according to the "three sigma" rule).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="minValue">Minimum value of the range.</param>
        /// <param name="maxValue">Maximum deviation value.</param>
        /// <returns>Random double precision floating point number.</returns>
        public double NextDoubleInterval(double minValue, double maxValue)
        {
            if (minValue > maxValue)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(minValue));
            }
            double diff = maxValue - minValue;
            double deviation = diff / 6;
            double expectation = diff / 2;
            return minValue + Sample() * deviation + expectation;
        }
    }
}
```